# Docker Zeppelin Image Spark Interpreter's configuration

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have installed Zeppelin using a docker image. Everything is OK. But now I'm trying to launch a spark notebook in my mesos cluster. I've already configured the master property of the spark interpreter and also the SPARK_HOME variable.

The thing is that the path of SPARK_HOME is outside the docker container so obviously is not finding the path. How can I set correctly this path pointing to the host path?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with the specifics of spark/zeppelin, but if you need a host path to be accessible from inside the container, use volume attribute.

Something like the following:

docker run -v %path to spark home on the host%:%path to spark home inside the container, e.g /spark %

Then specify the second path in zeppelin's settings